# NSSortDescriptor sort by max property value in NSSet

Tags: objective-c, core-data, nssortdescriptor, kvc

I am trying use `NSSortDescriptor` and sorts "Units" which have a set of "Devices". Each device has a signal strength. I would like to sort units by the device with the highest signal strength. I just found a page about collection operators and I think I'm close but I still can't quite get it to work.

```
NSSortDescriptor *rssiSortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"devices.@max.signalStrength" ascending:[self sortByRSSIAscending]];
```

I'm guessing the issue here is that devices can't be directly compared to each other, so the @max operator doesn't work. Is there a way to override this to compare by signal strength?

I have added this to my device model:

```
- (NSComparisonResult)compare:(PersistedNokeDevice*)other
{
if (self.signalStrength < other.signalStrength) {
    return NSOrderedAscending;
}
if (self.signalStrength == other.signalStrength) {
    return NSOrderedSame;
}
return NSOrderedDescending;
}
```

I am getting this error `Keypath containing KVC aggregate where there shouldn't be one; failed to handle devices.@max.signalStrength`

Is there a way to make this work or do I need to rethink my strategy?

Comment: How are `devices` and `signalStrength` declared? How do you use `rssiSortDescriptor`?

Comment: @willeke I was trying to use it in conjunction with nsfetchedresultscontroller. The rssiSortDescriptor was intended to be used in the collection operator, I don't think that's going to work though. signalStrength is a property on device. Unit has an NSSet of devices. Using the `[aUnit valueForKeyPath:@"devices.@max.signalStrength"]` prints the expected value. So I think core data queries can't work with the custom compare method I created.

Comment: A Core Data fetch can't use the custom compare method with the SQLite store but the custom compare method would be used if you want to sort devices. A Core Data fetch also can't use collection operators in sort descriptors.